# How to fix Forbidden 403 error caused by SpringSecurity?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I'm running spring boot app and I can't RequestParam from an HTML form. Whenever I'm trying to send param via form using POST method it throws Forbidden 403 error. Even when I've changed spring security settings to anyRequest.permitAll it still throws 403. Any idea how to fix this problem?

mastermind_home.jsp:

```
<form action="/mastermind/home" method="POST">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="easy">
            </label>Easy<br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="medium" checked>
            </label>Medium<br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="difficulty" value="hard">
            </label>Hard<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Start game">
        </form>`
```

Controller:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
@RequestMapping("mastermind")
public class MastermindController {

private MastermindServiceImpl mastermindService;
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/home")
public String prepareMmHomePage() {
    return "mastermind_home";
}
@PostMapping("/home")
public String formRequest( @RequestParam String difficulty) {
    return "mastermind_home";
}
```

Spring security settings:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private DataSource dataSource;

public SecurityConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public Authentication authentication() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws   Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, password, true FROM users WHERE user_name = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT user_name, 'ROLE_USER' FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/main_menu","/mastermind/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/home", "/register", "/registered_successfully").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/main_menu")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/home");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling csrf in spring security config fixed my problem.

```
and()
.csrf().disable();
```

Another and better solution to my problem:
 In spring security I have added:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mastermind/home").authenticated()
```

and in the jsp form a token validating csrf:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Spring security config you specific that all requests to URLs starting with `/mastermind` need to be authenticated (`.antMatchers("/main_menu","/mastermind/**").authenticated()`).

If you want to make an exception for `POST /mastermind/home` then you need to change your config to look something like below

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/mastermind/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/main_menu","/mastermind/**").authenticated()
        ....
```

Please note that the order of these two lines is important as Spring matches the request URL in that same sequence.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Still 403 forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to spring security to ignore url pattern

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring()
            // All of Spring Security will ignore the requests.
            .antMatchers("/mastermind/home");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 ..........
}
```

Comment: Using your method I was able to POST param and I didn't get any exception, but now I can't get user from session...

Comment: The configuration given completely ignores the url pattern from spring security so no session if you need session then this solution will not work